# With no new app binary submit. New in app purchase products stuck in "Waiting for Review"?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Scenario:
I didn't submit a new version of app binary, because I still in developing.
(I already)
But I do have new IAP product in this new version app. Therefore, I submit IAP products to App store connect, and submit for review.

After 16 hours, my new in app purchase products still in "Waiting for review" status.

Am I must submit a new version app to connect, and "submit for review", in order to make IAP products get review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After over 24 hrs, My IAPs products got reviewed, and passed the review. Therefore, I answer my question that is no need to build new version of app, in order to get IAP product be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, when you send a product for review you need to send a new build as well because the Apple reviewer will try to purchase the new product.